# Styling in React Native Slow Workflow

Tags: react-native

Perhaps this question is a bit obtuse for StackOverflow...

I'm wondering what the fastest workflow for styling a react native app is.  Currently I have to change my stylesheet, i.e; add marginBottom:5 to a button... save, reload the app in the simulator or on my phone (in expo) navigate to where the component is and repeat.  It's TERRIBLE for noodling around.  Is there an easier way to do this?  I know building natively in xcode at least you have the layout there in front of you... the way I do it currently is so incredibly tedious.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Use *Hot Reload*: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: Jesus, how did I miss that??  so much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Expo you just need to shake your device and enable Hot Reloading and disable Live Reloading. When you save your modified file, your app will change only the code that you modified, and not the whole js buddle, so, your app will keep the state and stay at the same screen.

UPDATE: to mac os users you can also use [react studio](https://reactstudio.com/) , it's opensource!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Storybook for React Native](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/app/react-native) to check simple ui components and better debugging on state I would highly recommend [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron). It also have storybook plugin which is quite good.